# Python array conversion to a string

Tags: python, arrays, text-files

I am trying to write the contents of a re.findall to a file. I tried

```
output_file.write (findall(tags_pattern, searchtext))
```

but I got a type error. How do I convert this to a type that can be written to a file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to JSON-encode it. See the json module.

Answer (score 1):

you have the `str(res)` and `repr(res)` function but you could also do `','.join(res)`

Answer (score 1):

`re.findall` returns a list of matches found in `searchtext` for `tags_pattern`. Those matches are just strings. The easiest way to convert a list of strings into a single string which can be written to a file is to call `str.join` on a string representing the separator you want to insert between the strings in the list. For example, you may call `'\n'.join(findall(tags_pattern, searchtext))` if you want to store each match on its own line.

Answer (score 1):

The [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) module is built to quickly store Python structures in a file.  It is not nearly as portable as JSON or some other serialization format, but depending on your purposes, it may be just enough.

To use pickle:

```
import re, pickle
r = re.findall(pattern, text)
with open('results.pkl', 'wb') as resultsfile:
    pickle.dump(r, resultsfile)
```

To recover the list, use `pickle.load`:

```
with open('results.pkl', 'rb') as resultsfile:
    r2 = pickle.load(resultsfile)
```

I'd be wary of using this in production code, or where you need to transmit the re.findall results to a web client, but for quick testing and local storage, this is probably the easiest.